# WFLYEJB0383: No message listener of type javax.jms.MessageListener found in resource adapter activemq-rar.rar

Tags: jboss, amq

I'm seeing the above error when trying to start Jboss 7.1.  Please help!
Note, the file activemq-rar.rar is in the standalone\deployments directory.  Also, here's the relevant updates i made to the standalone\configuration\standalone.xml file (please note the below is abbreviated.. the xml is wellformed).  Also note, I was able to get this setup to work with JBoss 6.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:5.0">
    <mdb>
            <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="activemq-rar.rar"/>
            <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
        </mdb>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:5.0">
            <resource-adapters>
                <resource-adapter id="activemq-rar.rar">
                    <archive>
                        activemq-rar.rar
                    </archive>
                    <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                    <config-property name="ServerUrl">
                        tcp://localhost:61616?jms.rmIdFromConnectionId=true
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="UserName">
                        admin
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="Password">
                        admin
                    </config-property>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/ConnectionFactory" enabled="true" pool-name="ConnectionFactory">
                            <xa-pool>
                                <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                                <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                                <prefill>false</prefill>
                                <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                            </xa-pool>
                            <recovery>
                                <recover-credential>
                                    <user-name>defaultUser</user-name>
                                    <password>defaultPassword</password>
                                </recover-credential>
                            </recovery>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
```

Comment: [This](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/172319) might help you out - sorry I dont have a ton of time to research at the moment and review your config

Comment: Need to look for duplicate references to .rar or its jar deployment.The problem was a dependency in the ear archive to the resource adapter jar. This was also the reason to get the same error when I deploy the resource adapter inside the ear. If the resource adapter is deployed as a subdeploment module in the ear, the ear archive only needs a dependency to the rar archive and not to the embedded jar.

use the "jboss-deployment-structure descriptor" in the ear archive and a maven dependency to the resource adapter api in the ear archive.

Comment: Try to put the rar module definition before the ejb module and add a jboss-deployment-structure descriptor, to define that the ejb subdeploment depends on the rar deployment in the ear archive.